# Excluding mysql query results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is an image of my table:

[image: client table]

I want to select all the rows where class_id does not equal 48, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE `class_id` != '$class_id' AND user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']."
```

Here's the problem, as you can see there is a row for Steve Puddin Robinson with class_id 48 and class_id 64. Since this person is already in class 48 I want to exclude there name from the result as well. Does that make sense and is this possible without passing the specific `first_name` `last_name` and `nickname` to the query

**Working Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `clients` 
WHERE `user_id`= ".$_SESSION['user_id']." AND `nickname` 
NOT IN(SELECT `nickname` FROM `clients`
WHERE `class_id` = '$class_id')
```

**Modified Query**

```
SELECT c.* FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN clients c1
ON `c1`.`first_name` = `c`.`first_name`
AND `c1`.`last_name` = `c`.`last_name`
AND `c1`.`nickname` = `c`.`nickname`
AND `c1`.`class_id` = 48
WHERE `c1`.`class_id` IS NULL;
```

Comment: are `last_name` and `nickname` interchangeable?

Comment: Also, as written, your query is open to SQL Injection; we recommend rewriting it to use parameterized queries.

Comment: What do you mean by interchangeable

Comment: User_I'd is all over the place, you could add to the end of the query 'AND class_I'd != 48

Comment: @ronanc that is what I am doing if I am understanding you correctly. The results of this query are put into a checkbox form and each checked name is then added to the `class_id 48`. The way it is setup now I would be able to add `Steve` to the class again because the query would pull the row with the `class_id 64`. This is what I want to exclude

Comment: so you mean `Steve "Puddin" Robinson` is the same as `Steve "Robinson" Puddin`?

Comment: @KuyaJohn that is the same person I just had the fields flipped when I inserted the data. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT * FROM clients
WHERE nickname NOT IN
(SELECT nickname FROM clients
 WHERE class_id = 48)
```

or, if the combination of both First name, Last name and nickname is needed to identify the clients, this one:

```
SELECT c.* FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN clients c1
ON c1.first_name = c.first_name
AND c1.last_name = c.last_name
AND c1.nickname = c.nickname
AND c1.class_id = 48
WHERE c1.class_id IS NULL
```

Check [SQLfidle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a9a4/5/0) to test it.

Comment: Thank you sir....worked like a charm I had to change just a little but it works. Thank you!!!!!

Comment: on you added query what if I want to get all rows with `class_id = 29` as well? I tried several different ways but couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Do you want to _exclude_ the users belonging to class 29 as well as the ones belonging to class 48?  If so, change the last part of the join condition to `AND c1.class_id IN (29, 48)`

Comment: No, I want only rows with a user_id=29 to be returned. The query you wrote worked but it returned rows that were not setup by the user logged in, in this case 29

Comment: Then you must select the ones `WHERE c.user_id = 29 AND c1.class_id IS NULL`

Comment: That returns the row of `Steve Robinson Puddin` which I dont want because it is in `class_id=48` already.

Comment: Then it must have been returned before adding he test for user_id = 29 as well. Was it?

Comment: Yes it was, just in the 2nd query you wrote not the original. I like the 2nd idea better in the case I dont want the user to have to imput something for nickname.

Comment: Check for spelling errors. The query works in SQLfiddle, check link in answer.

Comment: very strange. I can copy your exact query and i get different results.

Comment: That depends on the error. Writing `AND c.class_id = 48` _i.e_ not *c1* would give the error you observed.

Comment: I added my query above and Im still getting different results. Can you see what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that your data structure doesn't work properly. You're basing your connection on their name, which will likely fail at some point. Is there no unique ID per person? I see a client_id and user_id, but these don't suggest a global ID for a person.

What if there are two "Steve Smiths" ?

Comment: That is why I added the nickname column to give more options. I didnt really know any other way to set it up since a client will be able to have multiple entries with only the class_id being different